# Unable to pass inner class of a generic subclass using bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

**Disclaimer**: This question contains code using `rxjava` library, but the problem is not related to it. I provide all info required to allow those unfamiliar with that library to answer.

I have the following method that selects a data source based on if some data is cached or not:

```
public Observable<? extends MetricDataSource> createForOwners() {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<? extends MetricDataSource>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<? extends MetricDataSource> call() {
            if (ownersCache.isCached()) {
                return cacheMetricDataSource;
            } else {
                return androidApiMetricDataSource;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error:(29, 26) error: method defer in class Observable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
required: Func0<Observable<T#1>>
found: <anonymous Func0<Observable<? extends MetricDataSource>>>
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
(argument mismatch; <anonymous Func0<Observable<? extends MetricDataSource>>> cannot be converted to Func0<Observable<T#1>>)
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>defer(Func0<Observable<T#1>>)
T#2 extends Object declared in class Observable
```

The signature of `Observable.defer` is:

```
public final static <T> Observable<T> defer(Func0<Observable<T>> observableFactory)
```

`Func0` basically contains a `call()` method that returns an object of the generic type:

```
public interface Func0<T> { T call(); }
```

The data sources are declared as:

```
private final Observable<AndroidApiMetricDataSource> androidApiMetricDataSource;
private final Observable<CacheMetricDataSource> cacheMetricDataSource;
```

So, why it fails? `defer` is expecting an `Observable<T>` and I'm giving it an `Observable<? extends MetricDataSource>`, which should fit well in that `T`.

**Edit**: If I substitute the `defer` method by a private one in the current class and then replace `Observable<T>` to `T` in both the argument and return type, it compiles. However, I have to use the original `Observable` method.

So, this way it fails:

```
private static <T> Observable<T> defer(Func0<Observable<T>> observableFactory) {
    return null;
}
```

And this one it compiles:

```
private static <T> T defer(Func0<T> observableFactory) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Think of `Func0` as `Supplier` and `Observable` as `Iterable` if that makes the issue more  familiar)

Here, Func0 and Observable are intuitively covariant; in Java, they should almost always be used with wildcards, otherwise sooner or later problems will creep up.

The signature of `defter` can certainly be blamed here

```
<T> Observable<T> defer(Func0<Observable<T>> observableFactory)
```

it could have been more general, as

```
<T> Observable<? extends T> defer(Func0<? extends Observable<? extends T>> observableFactory)
```

But this also leads to wildcard hell... I can't see the types over the sound of wildcard screaming.

We could instead, live dangerously, and just omit wildcards - when problems come up, do some casting to workaround it. In your case, we need to cast `Observable<Subtype>` to `Observable<Supertype>`. This is obviously safe, and there's no guilt to do it.

Comment: my writing on wildcard - [wildcard hell](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Wildcard_Hell), [missing wildcard](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Missing_Wildcards)

Comment: Very useful answer, although I already solved it in other way (see my answer). I have a question on your answer. The cast works if I enclose it in a method similar to your `vary()` example on the second link. It only issues a warning of unchecked cast. But if I try the cast directly without the method, it fails to compile with a `Incompatible types` error. Why, if it is doing the same thing?

Comment: yes, your solution works (but then maybe it'll bump to problems too and require casting). see [casting between concrete types](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Casting_Between_Concrete_Types)

Comment: ok, so it is an unsafe cast, but as it is only used as a consumer and not as a producer, there will be no runtime problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this instead?

```
public <T extends MetricDataSource> Observable<T> createForOwners() {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call() {
        if (ownersCache.isCached()) {
            return cacheMetricDataSource;
        } else {
            return androidApiMetricDataSource;
        }
        }
    });
}
```

I am not certain, but I am guessing it's because if you're not binding it to T, it considers it references to different types that might change independently and thus are not equal. But not sure

Comment: Thanks! I had not tried it, but it fails with this error: `Error:(34, 28) error: incompatible types: Observable<CacheMetricDataSource> cannot be converted to Observable<T>
where T is a type-variable:
T extends MetricDataSource declared in method <T>createForOwners()`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez It works on my computer as well, try using javac to compile directly and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. I have copied it exactly as Oskar wrote. The only change is that now the error is only on the two `return` statements, and not in the whole anonymous class definition. I have found a solution and will post it now. Anyway, this was a helpful answer and I have upvoted it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like that if I change the declaration of the data sources from

```
private final Observable<AndroidApiMetricDataSource> androidApiMetricDataSource;
private final Observable<CacheMetricDataSource> cacheMetricDataSource;
```

to

```
private final Observable<MetricDataSource> androidApiMetricDataSource;
private final Observable<MetricDataSource> cacheMetricDataSource;
```

I can then declare the method to be

```
public Observable<MetricDataSource> createForOwners() {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<MetricDataSource>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<MetricDataSource> call() {
            if (ownersCache.isCached()) {
                return cacheMetricDataSource;
            } else {
                return androidApiMetricDataSource;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and now it compiles, as always an `Observable<MetricDataSource>` is returned.